# How to re-render already mounted component after route change in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

The component which holds `q-btn-dropdown` is already rendered before the route change. The route change occurs when the user logs in, so the `helloGuest()` is called only once when the component which has the `q-btn-dropdown`. So how do I re-render the component which holds the `q-btn-dropdown`, so that `helloGuest()` is called and the `q-btn-dropdown` updates?

```
methods: {
login() {
  this.$axios.post('login', this.formData).then(async (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    await localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res));
    await localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
    this.$router.push('/');
  }).catch((error) => {
    this.error = {
      email: error.response.data.message,
    };
  });
},


   <q-btn-dropdown flat dense
    :label="helloGuest()"
    class="gt-xs"
    >
 helloGuest() {
  const userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || {};
  console.log('[isauth]', this.isAuthenticated);
  console.log('[userName]', userName);
  console.log('[router]', this.$router);
  if (this.isAuthenticated) {
    // this.$forceUpdate();
    return `Hello ${userName.username}`;
  }
  return 'Sign In';
},
```

> my route file looks like this and I havent used mounted hook on the landing route

```
const routes = [{
path: '/',
component: () => import('layouts/MainDashboard.vue'),
children: [
  { path: '', component: () => import('components/FrontComponent.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: false } },
  { path: '/product_details/:productId', component: () => import('components/ProductDetails.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: false } },
  { path: '/cart', component: () => import('../cart/ShoppingCart.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: false } },
  { path: '/checkout', component: () => import('../cart/CheckoutComponent.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: false } },
  {
    path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: () => import('components/LoginComponent.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
  { path: '/register', component: () => import('components/RegisterComponent.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: false } },
],
```

Comment: Instead of method you should use `Computed` properties or methods.

Answer (score 1):

Vue can reuse the instance, when the component is same, so the `this.$route` in the component will change but `created()`, `beforeMounted()` and `mounted()` hooks won't be called.

To force vue to create a new component instance you can set a unique key on the like `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">`

Another options is to react to changes in the `$route` with a watcher:

```
watch: {
  "$route.params.cname": {
    handler(cname) {
      // do stuff
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried the unique key thing but it shows duplicatepath error when I use it and I cant use the second solution because I havent passed any params in router when logging in a user

Comment: In that case, please edit your question on how you are using router and mounted hook.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be use a watcher to watch $route and call a function on $route change